# Do capacitors need to be blown or bulged to be bad?

Tags: capacitor

The title says it all, I'm wondering if an electrolytic (or any other type) capacitor needs to be bulged to be bad?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, they don't.  There are various failure mechanisms, some of which don't exhibit bulging of the case.  Also bulging is pretty much limited to electrolytics.  Ceramics and other types don't do that because there isn't liquid electrolyte inside that can be electrolyzed, emit gasses, and thereby build up pressure.

Comment: otoh bulged elcos can be still "good" i.e. they have the necessary capacity.

Comment: @Plasm: A bulged capacitor is never "good".  Yes, they can still have the necessary electrical properties for the circuit to continue functioning.  But, some damage has already occured and some margin already used up.  The cap is now closer to (possibly catastrophic) failure than it was when new, and stresses that would otherwise be OK might tip it over the edge.

Comment: This is why I wrote it with quotes.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: My former employer had a television set which was damaged by lightning, and still worked fine except for smoke coming out the top.  During operation, one of the resistors inside was glowing (and smoking).  The insurance company wrote the set off as a loss and paid to replace it (probably figuring it would pose a fire risk otherwise) but I found it interesting that even with a resistor that was glowing (and whatever other damage was making it glow) the set worked perfectly in all other regards.

Comment: I have seen paper caps blow up.  If any cap which is across the power bus develops a short it's likely to go boom.

Comment: tantalums are probably the most fun, and explode very satisfyingly.

Comment: The real indication of whether a cap is okay or faulty is its [equivalent series resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance). You'll need an ESR meter to check that.

Comment: I had a power supply with a large electrolytic cap in it that had failed open, but otherwise looked normal.  Had to pull out the scope to find that one as it was a power supply filter cap.  Definitely possible to get a bad cap that looks normal.  I have also had to replace several ceramic caps that have failed short with no external indication.  I only found those after poking around with a multimeter.

Comment: I judge caps by different standards depending on context. At work, "bad" means `spec not met`. For personal/hobby projects, "bad" is `unsafe` or `causes the circuit to fail`.